# import variable from one file to another

Tags: python, numba

I need to import 2 variables from a main file into an additional one. These variables are used in the numba function of the additional file, which is called in the main.

main file:

```
import file2

SIGMA = 10
MEAN = 0

q = file2.compute(img)
```

additional file:

```
import numba as nb
from main import SIGMA, MEAN

@nb.njit('uint8[:,:,::1](uint8[:,:,::1])', parallel=True)
def compute(image):
    return = function(MEAN,SIGMA)
```

But the code threw:

```
File "D:\", line 5, in <module>
    from main import SIGMA, MEAN
File "D:\", line 18, in <module>
    q = file2.compute(img)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'file2' has no attribute 'compute' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)

Comment: The issue is that you are import things from main in file2 and stuff from file2 into main. That is a circular import. You can resolve that by for example moving the constants to another file an import them from there both in main and in file2

Answer (score 0):

Pass in parameters rather than importing constants

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('uint8[:,:,::1](uint8[:,:,::1])', parallel=True)
def compute(image, mean, sigma):
    return function(mean,sigma)  # the equal sign seems like a typo
```

Then, you can use

```
import file2

SIGMA = 10
MEAN = 0

q = file2.compute(img, SIGMA, MEAN)
```